# How i can reload ionic app if user turn on GPS

Tags: ionic-framework

I want that if user have not turned GPS on this code is prompting to turn GPS if user click on cancel it re-run   $scope.checkGPS(); and this prompt again user to turn on until user clicks on ok
What I want if user clicks on ok then it reload the windows
where I am wrong how to do this?

see screenshot of app

[image]

```
$scope.checkGPS = function (){


                     console.log("GPS Ceck ran");

                    cordova.plugins.locationAccuracy.canRequest(function(canRequest){
                        if(canRequest){
                            cordova.plugins.locationAccuracy.request(function (success){


                            },  function (error){
                                 console.error("Accuracy request failed: error code="+error.code+"; error message="+error.message);

                              if(error.code == 4){
                               console.error("while Accuracy request failed: error code="+error.code+"; error message="+error.message);

                                $scope.checkGPS();
                              }else(success.message == cordova.plugins.locationAccuracy.SUCCESS_USER_AGREED){

                                 console.log(" User OK ");

                               } 
                           // if(error.code !== cordova.plugins.locationAccuracy.ERROR_USER_DISAGREED){
                              //      if(window.confirm("Failed to automatically set Location Mode to 'High Accuracy'. Would you like to switch to the Location Settings page and do this manually?")){
                              //          cordova.plugins.diagnostic.switchToLocationSettings();
                              //      }
                              //  }
                            }, cordova.plugins.locationAccuracy.REQUEST_PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
                        }
                    });

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `$window.location.reload();` to reload the `window`

```
if(error.code == 4){
 console.error("while Accuracy request failed: error code="+error.code+"; error message="+error.message);
 $scope.checkGPS();
}else(success.message == cordova.plugins.locationAccuracy.SUCCESS_USER_AGREED){
   console.log(" User OK ");
   $window.location.reload();
}
```

add a loading overlay, that hides all content --> redirect to your initial state and call $window.location.reload();. It is like a full page reload.Loading layer is to hide some ugly effects until your app is ready again

Answer (score 0):

this code not worked but below one worked

Thanks for replying

```
if(error.code == 4){
 console.error("while Accuracy request failed: error code="+error.code+"; error message="+error.message);
 $scope.checkGPS();
}else if(success.message == cordova.plugins.locationAccuracy.SUCCESS_USER_AGREED){
   console.log(" User OK ");
   $window.location.reload();
}
```